# Change linear gradient background after a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to change a background after a time. If the background has got a "clear" color there is no problem but if the color is a gradient set as the code doesn't work. is there a work around for that?

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1)); /*For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));  /*For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1),rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));  /*For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1),rgba(51,90,109,1),rgba(83,142,144,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));  /*Standard syntax */
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s372ntyy/) for normal color change

Comment: have you tried css transitions in combination with 2 different css-classes (with 2 different gradients) (and each second you toggle those classes with js)?

Comment: Or you could go fully CSS with this, an example is here of how to use CSS keyframe animations [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

Comment: It depends on what browsers you want to target - keyframes being supported by only the latest browsers and a bit inconsistently. I'd go with a JS solution for the time being - or at least a combination of the two - worth noting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What Dbugger said is true - you can't animate a background image with css animations.

However, you could fake it with a 4 stop gradient (cleverly position your color stops  - I suggest using a gradient generator as [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) or similar - will make your work easier ) - since a gradient is treated as a `background-image`, you can animate it's position by using `background-position`. In order to animate the position you need to increase it's size so part of the gradient is outside your container.

You can use `animation-delay` to set the initial delay before the animation starts.

```css
html, body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(118,191,36,1) 25%, rgba(224,117,35,1) 50%, rgba(242,38,42,1) 75%, rgba(130,100,70,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(118,191,36,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(224,117,35,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(242,38,42,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(130,100,70,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(118,191,36,1) 25%,rgba(224,117,35,1) 50%,rgba(242,38,42,1) 75%,rgba(130,100,70,1) 100%);   
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(118,191,36,1) 25%,rgba(224,117,35,1) 50%,rgba(242,38,42,1) 75%,rgba(130,100,70,1) 100%);
    background-size: 100% 400%;
    background-position:0 0;
    -webkit-animation: animateGradient 5s ease 1;
    -moz-animation:    animateGradient 5s ease 1;
    animation:         animateGradient 5s ease 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:    2s;
    animation-delay:         2s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes animateGradient {
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    50%  {background-position: 0 100%;}
    100% {background-position: 0 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes animateGradient {
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    50%  {background-position: 0 100%;}
    100% {background-position: 0 0;}
}
@keyframes animateGradient { 
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    50%  {background-position: 0 100%;}
    100% {background-position: 0 0;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Alternative:** Another approach you could take is to overlay one element over the other, set the initial gradient in top and ending gradient in the bottom element , and create an opacity animation, that fades out the top element after a certain amount of time (`opacity: 0`)

Below is an approach on how you can do it with a single element in markup (rely on the `:after` or `:before` pseudo element). The following approach has more compatibility cross devices:

```css
html, body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;}
.gradient {
    position:relative;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1),rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(39,49,67,1),rgba(39,49,67,1), rgba(226,228,209,1));
}
.gradient:after {
   content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(226,228,209,1), rgba(39,49,67,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(226,228,209,1), rgba(39,49,67,1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(226,228,209,1), rgba(39,49,67,1));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(226,228,209,1), rgba(39,49,67,1));
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: animateGradient 3s linear 1;
    -moz-animation: animateGradient 3s linear 1;
    animation: animateGradient 3s linear 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateGradient {
    0%   {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes animateGradient {
    0%   {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes animateGradient {     
    0%   {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: I've done this before. http://codepen.io/rlemon/pen/hHrJe just another demo for OP

Answer (score 8):

## Gradient Animations

CSS3 doesn't support linear gradient animations, so in order to achieve this effect you'll have to write the animation your self in Javascript or use a background-position trick like the one stated by Easwee. I prefer Javascript because it allows you to easily reuse the code, add dynamic effects, and quickly modify the effect. That being said Easwee's solution is really ingenious although somewhat limiting.

## CSS based gradient animation:

Even though CSS doesn't natively support gradient animations as Easwee stated we can use a "hack" to create gradient animation in css by manipulating the background position of the image.

Example (Go full screen):

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 480px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 36px;
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  left: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  
  /* set up background gradient and animation */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5187c4, #1c2f45);
  background-size: auto 200%;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
.container:hover button {
  /* shift background gradient position */
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  right: 50px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5187c4, #1c2f45);
  transition: margin-top .5s;
}
.container:hover .slider {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  right: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 160px;
  height: 36px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.info {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  color: #ccc;
  font: 18px/150% sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button disabled>Some Button</button>
  <div class="slider"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>
</div>

<div class="info">
  You can't animate gradient colors with pure CSS. Gradients are set via background-image, which is not (currently) an animatable property. But background-position is. So you can use background-size to make the background taller than the element it's on, then animate background-position to slide it up or down. The result is a simple animated fading gradient.
</div>
```

[Code Pen Link](http://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/HiJDw)

## Javascript based gradient animation

In order to build a Javascript based gradient animation we need to:

- Create a function that takes an element, a range of colors, the time delay between them, and a callback which run's after the function ends (allowing you to do things like make it repeat continuously or till a condition is met).
- Have that function then use an interval that fires off 15 times a second and converts it's current time into a progress value from 0 - 100 on how close it is to finished.
- Then we multiply the difference in colors for each matching r,g,b by the progress to get what stage in the transition we're currently on.
- After we're finished we move on to the next color.
- At the end of all of this we launch the callback, so we can then decide what to do.

(If you'd like a code solution let me know. It is a lengthy process to type up, so for that reason if you're only using this once and for two maybe three gradient colors use Eawee's solution. Otherwise Javascript's your friend.)

## A simpler example of a Javascript gradient animation:

```js
var colors = new Array(
  [62,35,255],
  [60,255,60],
  [255,35,98],
  [45,175,230],
  [255,0,255],
  [255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient()
{
  
  if ( $===undefined ) return;
  
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

 $('#gradient').css({
   background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
  
  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
    
    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    
  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
 body{
  background-color: #000000;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }

#gradient
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gradient" />
 </body>
</html>
```

[Javascript Based Gradient Animator (Code Pen)](http://codepen.io/quasimondo/pen/lDdrF)

## Helpful Resources:

[CSS Gradient Animator Generator](http://www.gradient-animator.com/)

[CSS Gradient Animator Walkthrough](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/animating-css3-gradients)

Comment: Congrats! I didn't expect my bounty to attract another excellent answer! You deserve it.

Answer (score 4):

A background-gradient is considered a `background-image`, and background images can **NOT** be animated through normal CSS transitions.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [LinearGradient.js](https://stealson.github.io/LinearGradient/) to create random and colorful linear gradients.